# Relationship between file shrink and used memory in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, memory, shrink

Some background info: this is a test SQL Server 2012, with restored databases from production servers, all of them with over 20% space available in the data file, up to even 50%. I'd rather restore as many databases on this test server than waste the limited storage space. So decided to shrink the data files.

The way I see it with `sys.dm_exec_requests`, it seems to be a connection between the reported `percentage_complete` for the shrink operation and the memory taken up by SQL Server. It looks like when SQL Server grabs all the available memory (configured maximum memory), the shrink slows down to a crawl. I assume the server tries to load as much data in memory to save I/O ?

Killing the shrink process seems to clear the memory (doesn't release it to the OS, but as I restart the data file shrink - it's fast again). Adding more memory to the OS helps as well. But for databases in the hundreds of GBs, it's a painful process.

Is there any proper way to do this ? Maybe an option to release the free space when restoring the backups ? Drop the indexes before the shrink and rebuild once done ?

Any good resources to read and understand how the shrink works, or on how the data files are organized ?

Comment: I never experienced the memory issue you describe here, but I can offer you this resource to read about shrinking: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/08/stop-shrinking-your-database-files-seriously-now/

Comment: Mentioned this is a test server to avoid this debate. No more data will be added to these dbs.

Comment: Shrinking a database file is a very IO intensive operation, so what you are seeing is a side effect of shrinking the database. What you can do is [shrink the database file in chunks](https://gist.github.com/TheRockStarDBA/e2d33152deb97a2e2f45). I have answered a sort of similiar [question here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/101217/8783).

Comment: Kin, have you used this script for user databases on 2012 ?
sysfiles only shows the master database on my server. Tested with sys.database_files as well, same result. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187997.aspx